# opengl es 2.0 cocos2d soft body texture mapping/rendering

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, box2d, texture-mapping

I'm trying to simulate a soft body with box2d. So far so good. But I can't get the texture mapping right. It works with "opengl es 1.0" but I can't make it work for 2.0.

The soft body is a circle made out of box2d objects.

```
- (void) draw {
triangleFanPos[0] = Vertex2DMake(innerCircleBody->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO - self.position.x,
                                 innerCircleBody->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO - self.position.y);
// Use each box2d body as a vertex and calculate coordinate for the triangle fan
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEGMENTS; i++) {
    b2Body *currentBody = (b2Body*)[[bodies objectAtIndex:i] pointerValue];
    Vertex2D pos = Vertex2DMake(currentBody->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO - self.position.x,
                                currentBody->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO - self.position.y);
    triangleFanPos[i+1] = Vertex2DMake(pos.x, pos.y);
}
// Loop back to close off the triangle fan
triangleFanPos[NUM_SEGMENTS+1] = triangleFanPos[1];

textCoords[0] = Vertex2DMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEGMENTS; i++) {

    GLfloat theta = M_PI + (deltaAngle * i);

    // Calculate the X and Y coordinates for texture mapping.
    textCoords[i+1] = Vertex2DMake(0.5+cosf(theta)*0.5,
                                   0.5+sinf(theta)*0.5);

}
// Close it off.
textCoords[NUM_SEGMENTS+1] = textCoords[1];

ccGLBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.name);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords );
glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleFanPos);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, textCoords);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NUM_SEGMENTS+2);    
}
```

where `NUM_SEGMENTS = 18` and `PTM_RATIO = 32`.

With my old "opnegl es 1.0" code I could do this and it would work:

```
    // Enable texture mapping stuff
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

// Bind the OpenGL texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture name]);

// Send the texture coordinates to OpenGL
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textCoords);
// Send the polygon coordinates to OpenGL
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, triangleFanPos);
// Draw it 
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, NUM_SEGMENTS+2);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2014/05/soft-bodies-with-cocos2d-v3.html, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @fiddler. actually I was missing a CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP() before the start of my opengl code